# how can I install python version <=3.7 in google colab without runtime crashing upon restart?

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, cloud, google-colaboratory

I am using python packages which require python version <= 3.7 but as I install it and then restarts it for using newly installed python libraries, the runtime never connects and keeps on crashing down as it tries to connect. The following is the code I am using for installation of older python3 version:

`#install python 3.7
!sudo apt-get update -y
!sudo apt-get install python3.7

#change alternatives
!sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/python3 python3 /usr/bin/python3.10 1
!sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/python3 python3 /usr/bin/python3.7 2

#check python version
!python --version
#3.7.16

## install pip for new python

!sudo apt-get install python3.7-distutils
!wget https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py
!python get-pip.py

## install colab's dependencies

!python -m pip install ipython ipython_genutils ipykernel jupyter_console prompt_toolkit httplib2 astor importlib-metadata

## link to the old google package

!ln -s /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/google 
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/google`

The following is the runtime log as the runtime crashes:

[!(https://i.stack.imgur.com/cPBFH.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cPBFH.png)

There are no connectivity issues and the internet speed is excellent.

I tried to install repeatedly during past several weeks but failed.